# ¿Como descripto datos en una blade de laravel?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un dato que viene del controlador encriptado, esto con la intención de que el usuario no vea un dato que traigo del controlador, no se si hay otra manera de hacer esto.

El dato lo encripto de la siguiente manera:

```
$valores = Respuesta::select(array(
    'respuestas.id',
    'respuestas.puntaje as punt_resp',
    'respuestas.v_f as v_f_resp',
    'respuestas.seleccion as seleccion_resp',
    'respuestas.desarrollo as desarrollo_resp',
    'preguntas.descrip',
    'preguntas.numero',
    'preguntas.tipo',
    'preguntas.puntaje as punt_preg',
    'preguntas.v_f as v_f_preg',
    'preguntas.seleccion as seleccion_preg',
    'preguntas.desarrollo as desarrollo_preg',
));

foreach($valores as $clave => $elemento){
    if($valores[$clave]["punt_resp"]){
        $valores[$clave]["punt_resp"] = Crypt::encrypt( $valores[$clave]["punt_resp"] );
    }
    if($valores[$clave]["v_f_preg"]){
        $valores[$clave]["v_f_preg"] = Crypt::encrypt( $valores[$clave]["v_f_preg"] );
    }
}
```

La columna donde esta el json de los datos encriptados los guardo en una variable y la recorro para desencriptar los datos, esto de la siguiente manera:

```
let array = data[10];
for(var i=0;i(menor que)array.length;i++){ //coloco "menor que" para indicar la condicion en el "for", sucede que la web me elimina todo lo siguiente al signo "menor que"
   array[i].punt_resp = '{{ \Crypt::decrypt( array[i].punt_resp ) }}';
}
```

Esto me arroja el siguiente error:

> syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting '('

**NOTA:**

Esto para evitar que el usuario lo pueda ver de esta manera:
[image: no encriptado]

Encriptado queda de la siguiente manera:
[image: encriptado]

Comment: Asumo que es una solicitud Ajax lo que muestras en el inspector?

Comment: @Shaz Inspector?

Comment: Devtools mejor :)

Comment: @Shaz ah ok, y si.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No lo he probado, pero según una [respuesta de SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32947967/495103), es posible hacer algo con un antiguo proyecto de Google: [CryptoJS](https://github.com/sytelus/CryptoJS)

1. Poner en el archivo .env:

   ```
   APP_KEY=uberkeythatrocks
   ```
2. Poner en config/app.php:

   ```
   'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC'
   ```
3. En el controlador:

   ```
   $mySecret = "Something I wanna hide from them";
   $encrypted = Crypt::encrypt($mySecret);
   ```
4. En la vista, en JS:

   ```
   var key = "uberkeythatrocks";
   var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key);
   var readable = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
   ```

IMPORTANTE: 'key' en PHP debe ser la misma 'key' en JS, y 'cipher' en PHP debe ser el mismo en JS, sin embargo CryptoJS seleccionará automáticamente AES-128-CBC o AES-256-CBC según la longitud de 'key'.

Comment: ok gracias lo probare y escribiré que tal me fue :D

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres que el usuario no lo vea, no se lo mandes, ni en claro ni encriptado. Si lo mandas cifrado para luego descifrarlo, tendrás que mandar la clave o la función de descifrado; con lo que un usuario avanzado siempre podrá verlo, dedicándole tiempo y ganas.

Puedes mandar un identificador a un valor almacenado en el servidor o algo similar. Pero cualquier cosa que mandes al navegador, has perdido el control sobre ella.